# Integrating Entity Framework Code First Classes With SQL Database Project And Deploying

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've currently got an ASP.NET MVC project, with three C# Class Libraries for Data Access, Settings and an Entity Framework Code First project.

I am currently trying to add a SQL Database Project to my solution so that I can manage my database more closely and add extra items that entity framework doesn't deal with.

I have searched around for integration options and can't find anything more helpful than going the DB first route and updating an edmx model from that.

How would I go about integrating my code first entity framework project with my SQL database project in a way that lets me edit the tables with code first and manage stored procedures and the rest with the database project.

If this is possible, is there any particular way to get these to deploy without conflicting?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean extra items that Entity Framework doesn't deal with? Do you have specifics?

Comment: Primarily I would like to add my own stored procedures to the database. I would also like to use dacpac to update my database as opposed to entity migrations. There are also other tables that I would like to add and not manage with Entity